# Where could I get the apparmor profile for latest Skype4? 

Tags: skype, apparmor

Where could I get the apparmor profile for latest Skype4? I tried to make my own based on previous skype version but there are too many errors while launching.

Answer (score 3):

A very late response but here's [Apparmor profile skype 4.1.0.20 - Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2088174) by [NikTh](https://askubuntu.com/users/95393/nikth) who acknowledged [this](http://eternalwalkabout.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/skype-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-apparmor/) as the source.

Although it is suggested that:

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be
>   preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for
>   reference.

In this case, I'm not sure much purpose will be served by pasting details of the profile here but if it is felt helpful I will.

Answer (score 0):

```
# HOWTO:
# $ sudo aa-genprof /usr/bin/skype
# $ sudo service apparmor restart
# $ sudo aa-enforce skype
# then monitor syslog and add more, if required

# INFO: man 5 apparmor.d
# Access modes:
# r - read
# w - write
# m -- allow PROT_EXEC with mmap()
# l -- link
# k -- lock
# *x -- different ways to execute. Best: ix

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/skype {
  #include <abstractions/audio>
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/kde>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/fonts>
  #include <abstractions/video>
  #include <abstractions/dbus>
  #include <abstractions/nvidia>
  #include <abstractions/X>

  # System
  /proc/sys/kernel/** r,
  @{PROC}/@{pid}/** r,
  /dev/ r,
  /dev/video* rw,

  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/cpu/** r,

  # Executables
  /usr/bin/skype mr,
  /usr/bin/pulseaudio rmix,

  # Root
  /etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf rk,
  /usr/share/** rk,
  /var/cache/fontconfig/** rwk,

  # Home
  owner @{HOME}/.Skype/ rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.Skype/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/Skype/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.kde/share/config/kioslaverc r,
  owner @{HOME}/.kde{,4}/share/config/kdeglobals rl,

  # Uploads to /tmp/tmp/
  /tmp/tmp/** rwk,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest Skype 4.3 better take profile in 
`/usr/share/doc/apparmor-profiles/extras/usr.bin.skype` in `apparmor-profiles` package